# Angular 5 component usage

Tags: angular, typescript

I am quite new to Angular 5 and I downloaded this starter template:

[Angular 5 - Firebas starter template](http://%20https://github.com/bave8672/angular-firebase-starter)

I have a dashboard component where I want to implement a chartjs component.

My dashboard.module.ts:

```
import { DashboardPageComponent } from './dashboard-page.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: DashboardPageComponent },
        ]),
    ],
    declarations: [DashboardPageComponent],
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

And here the dashboard.component.html template:

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Your Todo List</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <p>test</p>
    </ul>

    // HERE I WANT TO USE THE CHART COMPONENT
    <line-chart-component></line-chart-component>
</div>
```

Here is the linechart component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js'

@Component({
    selector: 'line-chart-component',
    templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html'
})
export class LineChartComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

And the linechart html:

```
    <div class="container">
      <h1>TESTCOMPONENT</h1>
    </div>
```

And the chart module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LineChartComponent } from './line-chart.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LineChartComponent],
    // export: [LineChartComponent],
})
export class LineChartModule {}
```

But the export declaration is not assignable to parameter of type "NgModule"

How can I use the chart component in the dashboard component?

Comment: it's exports, not export

Comment: @marko than it throws me this error: errors:
'line-chart-component' is not a known el…, …}

Comment: The link you cite is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `exports` not `export`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [LineChartComponent],
    exports: [LineChartComponent],
})
```